# Getting 404 error on loading 3D model of autodesk forge

Tags: manifest, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am working on the Autodesk forge 3D models (.rvt,.ifc,.pdf etc) .And when I select any model and it uses [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/regions/eu/manifest/{urn}](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/regions/eu/manifest/%7Burn%7D) api to load the model after that If I open any model it won't open because of the 404 error. And if I open that particular model for the very first time It loads properly.

Can anyone help me finding the reason of 404 (model not found) on autodesk developer api?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using OSS (buckets/objects), you must ensure the [Data Retention Policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) of the bucket where your files are. If your bucket is `transient`, files are deleted after 24 hours.

Using [Get bucket details](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-details-GET/) endpoint, you'll find the retention policy of your bucket.

Then you can also use [Get Objects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/) endpoint to list files in bucket.